# How to create an static api route after a dynamic route in Next.js?

Tags: api, next.js, url-routing

I have an api that dynamically pulls a post. `localhost/api/post/[postId]`

I want to extend functionality to retrieve the comments of the post at the URL `localhost/api/post/[postId]/comments`

What is the correct way to structure this in Next.js? I am thinking to create a dynamic route and check if the query equals comment? `localhost/api/post/[postId]/[comment]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following file structure should work:

```
/pages/api/post/[postId]/index.js       //Route: /api/post/1
/pages/api/post/[postId]/comments.js    //Route: /api/post/1/comments
```

Besides that, just to follow good practices, I would recommend that you rename "post" to "posts", like that:

```
/pages/api/posts/[postId]/comments.js
```